# Working with webinpectord

Tags: ios, curl, safari, mobile-safari, google-chrome-devtools

I just want to communicate with Mobile Safari using 'webinpectord' (hobby project). My aim is to just display an alert 'hi' on Mobile Safari. I know I can do this using Safari's debugging console. At the moment what things I know is Mobile Safari ('webinpectord') listen to port 27753 on localhost using IPV6 protocol. And from [this](https://github.com/leftlogic/remote-debug/blob/master/safari/sequence.md) page I understand the sequense of communication with Mobile Safari. I perused already working programs like [remote-debug](https://github.com/leftlogic/remote-debug), [node-iosdriver](https://github.com/andydavies/node-iosdriver/) and [iOS-webkitproxy](https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy). Then I tried to write a program in C which connects to localhost:27753 and then send and receive commands. My problem is I can connect and send commands to port 27753 but not getting any response from that port.

I tried to send

```
{ __argument: { WIRConnectionIdentifierKey: '17858421-36EF-4752-89F7-7A13ED5782C5' },
   __selector: '_rpc_reportIdentifier:' }
```

According to [this](https://github.com/leftlogic/remote-debug/blob/master/safari/sequence.md) article, Mobile Safari has to send back response like

```
{ __selector: '_rpc_reportSetup:',
 __argument: 
   { WIRSimulatorNameKey: 'iPhone Simulator',
     WIRSimulatorBuildKey: '10A403' } }


{ __selector: '_rpc_reportConnectedApplicationList:',
 __argument: 
     { WIRApplicationDictionaryKey: 
        { 'com.apple.mobilesafari': 
           { WIRApplicationIdentifierKey: 'com.apple.mobilesafari',
              WIRApplicationNameKey: 'Safari',
              WIRIsApplicationProxyKey: false } } } }
```

but I am not getting any response from Mobile Safari. I just can send commands to there.

Let us assume that my program is buggy !

So I tried to experiment with 'telnet'. Here also I can connect to localhost:27753 and I can send commands and not getting any response. I am attaching screen shot.

[image: Sending Connection Identifier Key]
[image]

You can see that I tried many combinations like

```
  { "__argument": { "WIRConnectionIdentifierKey": "17858421-36EF-4752-89F7-7A13ED5782C5" }, "__selector": "_rpc_reportIdentifier: " }


  {\"__argument\": { \"WIRConnectionIdentifierKey\": \"17858421-36EF-4752-89F7-7A13ED5782C5\" }, \"__selector\": \"_rpc_reportIdentifier: \"}


  "{ "__argument": { "WIRConnectionIdentifierKey": "17858421-36EF-4752-89F7-7A13ED5782C5" }, "__selector": "_rpc_reportIdentifier: " }"
```

but nothing worked.

Lastly I tried curl to send data. That also failed !

[image]

**Can anybody tell me what should I do to get response like**

```
  { __selector: '_rpc_reportSetup:',
 __argument: 
   { WIRSimulatorNameKey: 'iPhone Simulator',
     WIRSimulatorBuildKey: '10A403' } }


{ __selector: '_rpc_reportConnectedApplicationList:',
 __argument: 
     { WIRApplicationDictionaryKey: 
        { 'com.apple.mobilesafari': 
           { WIRApplicationIdentifierKey: 'com.apple.mobilesafari',
              WIRApplicationNameKey: 'Safari',
              WIRIsApplicationProxyKey: false } } } }
```

**when sending request**

```
  { __argument: { WIRConnectionIdentifierKey: '17858421-36EF-4752-89F7-7A13ED5782C5' },
   __selector: '_rpc_reportIdentifier:' }
```

**to localhost:27753 using 'telnet' or 'curl'.**

I tried two days in different ways (wrote C program, python program and lastly tried telnet and curl) and did not get succeeded. So please help !

Answer (score 0):

1. Mobile Safari use customized binary protocol(binary property list, see [bplist-creator](https://github.com/joeferner/node-bplist-creator)) to communicate with Safari debugging mode.
2. The correct format for this JSON command should be this:

   ```
   {"__argument":{"WIRConnectionIdentifierKey":"990cc163-d8b2-4d22-8d1c-644e100a5a07"},"__selector":"_rpc_reportIdentifier:"}
   ```

Notice that every "key" should be double quoted.

You can refer the [appium](https://github.com/appium/appium) for details.